# Symfony Sylius Install Fails

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am trying to install Sylius following https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius or http://sylius.org/get-started but no way, all times I get an error in the terminal :

```
>php app/console sylius:install
Installing Sylius...
Step 1 of 4. Checking system requirements.
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
----------------------+
| Issue | Recommendation
|
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
----------------------+
| short_open_tag |
|
| session.auto_start |
|
| sylius.extensions.accelerator | Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC
(highly recommended). |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
----------------------+
Success! Your system can run Sylius properly.

Step 2 of 4. Setting up the database.
Creating Sylius database for environment dev.
The command terminated with an error code: 1.
[Exception]
The command terminated with an error code: 1.
```

and here is few lines of my log :

```
[2015-07-21 17:51:59] php.DEBUG: "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\TableHelper" is deprecated since version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. Use "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table" instead. {"type":16384,"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet.php","line":86,"level":4352} []
[2015-07-21 17:51:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-21 17:51:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2015-07-21 17:52:00] doctrine.DEBUG: SHOW DATABASES [] []
[2015-07-21 17:52:00] php.DEBUG: "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper" is deprecated since version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. Use "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar" instead. {"type":16384,"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet.php","line":84,"level":4352} []
[2015-07-21 17:52:00] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2015-07-21 17:52:00] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-21 17:52:00] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-21 17:52:00] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-07-21 17:52:00] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception: The command terminated with an error code: 1. {"type":1,"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor.php","line":81,"level":16383,"stack":[{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\AbstractInstallCommand.php","line":122,"function":"runCommand","class":"Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor","type":"->","args":["doctrine:database:create",[]]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\InstallDatabaseCommand.php","line":50,"function":"runCommands","class":"Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\AbstractInstallCommand","type":"->","args":[["doctrine:database:create","doctrine:schema:create","cache:clear","doctrine:phpcr:repository:init"],"object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\InstallDatabaseCommand","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php","line":886,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php","line":195,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object","object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php","line":96,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php","line":126,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor.php","line":74,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\InstallCommand.php","line":48,"function":"runCommand","class":"Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor","type":"->","args":["sylius:install:database",[],"object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\InstallCommand","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php","line":886,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php","line":195,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object","object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php","line":96,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php","line":126,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object","object"]},{"file":"E:\_projects\symfony\sylius-standard\app\console","line":17,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\Component\Console\Application","type":"->","args":["object"]}]} []
```

Does anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong or missing please ?

----------- Edit

Well I remove my pre created db, created trought terminal, db creation works well :

```
>php app/console doctrine:database:create
Created database for connection named `sylius`
```

But then I get different errors in terminal now :

```
Step 2 of 4. Setting up the database.
Creating Sylius database for environment dev.
The command terminated with an error code: 1.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The command termi
nated with an error code: 1.' in E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\I
nstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor.php:81
Stack trace:
#0 E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\Abstrac
tInstallCommand.php(122): Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor-
>runCommand('doctrine:databa...', Array)
#1 E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\Install
DatabaseCommand.php(50): Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\AbstractInstallCo
mmand->runCommands(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Ob
ject(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Cons
ole\Command\Command.php(245): Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\InstallDatab
aseCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(S
ymfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\vendor\sy in E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\src\Syli
us\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor.php on line 81

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The command terminated
 with an error code: 1.' in E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\Instal
lerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor.php on line 81

Exception: The command terminated with an error code: 1. in E:\_projects\symfony
\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Command\CommandExecutor.php on line 81


Call Stack:
    0.0000     124368   1. {main}() E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\app\console:0
    0.1250    2980672   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() E:\_proj
ects\symfony\sylius\app\console:26
```

Comment: Can you run `app/console doctrine:database:create` and post it's output?

Comment: sure ! well it throws an error as my db exists already because I usually create it with attached user :
>php app/console doctrine:database:create
Could not create database for connection named `sylius`
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `sylius`':
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'sylius'; database exists

Comment: Try dropping the DD and running the Sylius installation again. (Don't create the DB before running the instalation)

Comment: I tried install after removing db, please have a look to my question edit for some errors I get in terminal

Comment: I tried both with or without db creation, if no db it tells db is missing :) then see again my edit for errors

Comment: Ok, drop all sylius_* db's, then run this commands in this order: `app/console doctrine:database:create`, 
`app/console doctrine:schema:create`, 
`app/console cache:clear`, 
`app/console doctrine:phpcr:repository:init` and post the result of the failing one.

Comment: What is strange is there are more verbose errors if db has been created with terminal...

Comment: well it seems I got a memory problem while clearing cache, I check what's wrong and I tell you back, thank you for your help.

Comment: Well now all commands works well but command cache:clear, it throws the error :

  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
  Cannot rename "E:\_projects\symfony\sylius\app\cache\de_" to "E:\_projects\
  symfony\sylius\app\cache\dev".

seems related to https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2604
I think the last download I tried is the https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius one and so version 0.14.0

Comment: chck if this folder exists and remove it manually `E:_projects\ symfony\sylius\app\cache\dev`, then try again

Comment: I already tried removing manually, even my cache is empty, clearing cache throws this error